# How to use TintSpinner in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi all I want to use `TintSpinner` in my application. But when I tried to import it, error occurred as :

`can not resolve symbol TintSpinner`.

I had imported it as:

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintSpinner;
```

But at import also it gives me error as :

`can not resolve symbol TintSpinner`

In dependencies I had added :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance